# What kind of router will deal with RJ45 as internet source

Tags: wireless-networking, router

There is RJ45 cable hanging out of my wall. I can connect it to the laptop and connect to the internet. What kind of router should I use to have wifi in my apartment? ADSL, DSL, XDSL?

Is this will work? http://www.komputronik.pl/product/146654/Sprzet_komputerowy_/Sieci_i_komunikacja/TP_Link_router_DSL_Wi_Fi_150Mb-s_TL_WR743ND.html

My problem is that I do not know if this RJ45 cable will be treated as another PC in the local network or source of internet.

Answer (score 1):

You should look for a simple wifi router, not including any modem module.

One of the ethernet ports of such routers will be special (different color in most cases), and is the one designed to be the Internet source, and thus the one you'll connect to the cable hanging out of your wall.

It would be the blue one on the example you provided.

Comment: I have seen many ADSL/Cable modems with WAN ports.  Thats really all that is required for a gateway to act as a router.